# Removing ListBoxItem background for right click events

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, listboxitem

I have managed to prevent the `ListBox` item background from displaying on hover and selection, however, it appears when I right click an item and then even shows the background on hover when the `ListBox` has focus again (for the element that was previously right clicked).

I can't use `e.Handled = true` in `ListBoxPreviewMouseDown` as that breaks my right click context menus. By break, I mean that it prevents the menu items from reacting to clicks. The context menu displays fine, but cannot invoke the item clicks.

What am I missing to also cover the `ListBoxItem` background not displaying upon right click?

Thank you.

```xml
<!-- Style -->
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="MyListBoxItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />

                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- Listbox -->

<ListBox Name="ListBoxOne">
        <ListBox.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ListBox.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter 
                            Property="ListBox.ItemContainerStyle" 
                            Value="{StaticResource MyListBoxItemStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Style>
    </userControls:ListBox>
```

Comment: why not use `ItemsControl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just always set the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the `ListBox` to your custom style, i.e. don't set it in a trigger inside the `Style`:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxOne">
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyListBoxItemStyle}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: That fixed the problem completely. This was certainly a case of not seeing the wood for the trees. Thanks for the help!